# What are good commercial alternatives for MS Expression Encoder SDK for C# development?

Tags: video, c#, sdk

I am using MS Expression Encoder in my C# application to convert video files from one format to multiple other formats, re-encode source video files at lower bitrate and to cut out and re-encode chunks of the source video file.

Since Microsoft discontinued their Expression Encoder quite some time ago, I am looking for a solid commercial (not free, not open source) alternatives.

Please, believe me, I've done my google search and so far I am not sure which way to go. Search showst that OBS and ffmpeg are the alternatives, but these products are open source and do not offer support and do not require a purchase.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a commercial product, the LEADTOOLS SDK has multiple encoders and components to facilitate conversion to other formats.  We have a list of formats we can convert to and from on our product page.
https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/formats/multimedia-formats

Specific selections of the input video can be specified for encoding.  The output bit rate can be modified as well based on the encoder and conversion options.

Here's a code snippet showing how the SDK can convert a specific section of an input file to a new target output format using certain compressors:

```
  public void ConvertExample(string inputFile, string outputFile)
  {
     try
     {
        ConvertCtrl _convertctrl = new ConvertCtrl();

        // set the source for conversion 
        _convertctrl.SourceFile = inputFile;

        // set the video and audio compressors 
        _convertctrl.VideoCompressors.Mpeg2.Selected = true;
        _convertctrl.AudioCompressors.AC3.Selected = true;

        // set the target output file and format 
        _convertctrl.TargetFile = outputFile;

        // set the target output format 
        _convertctrl.TargetFormat = TargetFormatType.AVI;

        // if the source has a non-zero duration, convert it 
        if (_convertctrl.Duration > 0)
        {
           // set the selected area for conversion 
           _convertctrl.SelectionStart = 10;
           _convertctrl.SelectionEnd = 20;

           // start the capture process 
           _convertctrl.StartConvert();
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return;
     }
  }
```

The toolkit is available for a 60-day evaluation on the official site.  The installation package includes example programs as well as source code.  Support is also available during the evaluation.
https://www.leadtools.com/downloads

Note:  I work for the company which makes this product.